# CGAL static AABB tree to intersect many spheres with rays

Tags: cgal

I would like to use CGAL's AABB Tree to compute intersection between many static spheres and rays. I am fairly new to CGAL and might need some guidance.

As there does not seem to be direct support for spheres in the AABB tree, I *think* need to complement the functionality by creating `AABB_sphere_primitive`. Is that the only thing that is needed to get something like [AABB_tree/AABB_triangle_3_example.cpp](https://doc.cgal.org/latest/AABB_tree/AABB_tree_2AABB_triangle_3_example_8cpp-example.html), with spheres instead of triangles? Do I need to also define an analogue of `Point_from_triangle_3_iterator_property_map`?

```
typedef CGAL::Simple_cartesian<double> K;
typedef K::FT FT;
typedef K::Point_3 Point;
typedef K::Plane_3 Plane;
typedef K::Sphere_3 Sphere;          // <-- this is done already
typedef std::list<Sphere>::iterator Iterator;
typedef CGAL::AABB_sphere_primitive<K,Iterator> Primitive; // <---- must be defined newly
typedef CGAL::AABB_traits<K, Primitive> Traits;
typedef CGAL::AABB_tree<Traits> Tree;
```

The routine for intersection between sphere and ray is already implemented somewhere (`Spherical_kernel_intersections.h`?) and will be used?

Thanks for pointers.

Comment: did you get the result you wanted?

Comment: I gave up on CGAL (not the first time, anyway). I used https://github.com/brandonpelfrey/Fast-BVH instead, easy to use, fast.

Comment: cool, thanks for the link to Fast-BVH

Answer (score 0):

You need to provide a new primitive type that is a model of the concept [`AABBPrimitive`](https://doc.cgal.org/latest/AABB_tree/classAABBPrimitive.html). Basically you can copy/paste the implementation of `CGAL::AABB_triangle_primitive` and adapt it to the case of a sphere.
The next tricky part is to provide the intersection predicate for a ray and a sphere as required by the [`AABBTraits`](https://doc.cgal.org/latest/AABB_tree/classAABBTraits.html) concept.
If you are not looking for exact predicates, you can simply using the distance of the center of the sphere to the support line of the ray + the direction of the center of the sphere with reference to the source of the ray.

If you want exact predicates, the class [`Filtered_predicate`](https://doc.cgal.org/latest/Kernel_23/classCGAL_1_1Filtered__predicate.html) can help you make your predicate robust.